# Creating a Azure database copy and then loading production data every night into copy

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'd like to create an environment like the one shown in the pic. Are there any good tutorials out there that will help me create a copy of my production database (Sql Server in Azure) and then every night at a specific time load all the data from production into the copy (so I have data to work with in the copy while developing)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options that you can use.

Please check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/03/04/different-ways-to-backup-your-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx) and look under option 2. in particular.

You could set when will this be executed by using [Azure Scheduler](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) service that would run your [Azure WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) at the midnight. Azure WebJob would execute "CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF" command.